# Drawing elliptical arc with desired major and minor axis

Tags: tikz-pgf

So I am given two points and wish to draw an elliptical arc joining them. More specifically, my code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
[vertex/.style={circle,draw=black!100,fill=black!100,thick,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=1mm},]
\node (v1) at ( 0,0) [vertex,label=left:$v_1$] {};
\node (v2) at ( 1,0) [vertex,label=right:$v_2$] {};
\node (v3) at ( 1.35,1) [vertex,label=right:$v_3$] {};
\node (v4) at ( 0.5,1.75) [vertex,label=above:$v_4$] {};
\node (v5) at ( -0.35,1) [vertex,label=left:$v_5$] {};
\draw [-] (v1) to (v2);
\draw [-] (v2) to (v3);
\draw [-] (v3) to (v4);
\draw [-] (v4) to (v5);
\draw [-] (v5) to (v1);
\draw [-] (v3) to (v1);
%\draw [-] (v2) to [bend left=60] (v5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I wish to connect `v2 to v5` and `v2 to v4` without any intersection of edges. Now this is only possible if we draw elliptical arcs outside the pentagon. How can I draw those? I am unable to utilise bend left as it is not bending enough to go out of the pentagon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many possibilities like

```
%\draw [-] (v2) to [bend left=80, min distance=2cm] (v5);
%\draw [-] (v2) to [bend right=70, min distance=2cm] (v4);
%\draw [-] (v2) to [bend left=80, distance=2cm] (v5);
%\draw [-] (v2) to [bend right=70, distance=2cm] (v4);
\draw [-] (v2.center) to [controls=+(40:-2) and +(70:-2)] (v5.center);
\draw [-] (v2.center) to [controls=+(30:2) and +(30:2)] (v4.center);
```

The details of parameters used to control `bend` operation can be found in `pgfmanual` documentation, page 751 (especially  755 and 756) onwards in section 70.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
[vertex/.style={circle,draw=black!100,fill=black!100,thick,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=1mm},]
\node (v1) at ( 0,0) [vertex,label=left:$v_1$] {};
\node (v2) at ( 1,0) [vertex,label=right:$v_2$] {};
\node (v3) at ( 1.35,1) [vertex,label=right:$v_3$] {};
\node (v4) at ( 0.5,1.75) [vertex,label=above:$v_4$] {};
\node (v5) at ( -0.35,1) [vertex,label=left:$v_5$] {};
\draw [-] (v1) to (v2);
\draw [-] (v2) to (v3);
\draw [-] (v3) to (v4);
\draw [-] (v4) to (v5);
\draw [-] (v5) to (v1);
\draw [-] (v3) to (v1);
%\draw [-] (v2) to [bend left=80, min distance=2cm] (v5);
%\draw [-] (v2) to [bend right=70, min distance=2cm] (v4);
%\draw [-] (v2) to [bend left=80, distance=2cm] (v5);
%\draw [-] (v2) to [bend right=70, distance=2cm] (v4);
\draw [-] (v2.center) to [controls=+(40:-2) and +(70:-2)] (v5.center);
\draw [-] (v2.center) to [controls=+(30:2) and +(30:2)] (v4.center);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can adjust the angles and distances as in

```
\draw [-] (v2.center) to [controls=+(30:-3) and +(50:-3)] (v5.center);
\draw [-] (v2.center) to [controls=+(30:3) and +(30:3)] (v4.center);
```

which gives

[image]